# How to get Year only in Default Value or Binding

Tags: sql, create-table, ssms

I am using SQL  Server Management Studio to create a new table. I have a "HistoryYear" column that has a data type of datetime2.

How do I get the year only as the output? Do I change the data type? Or what do I put into the Default Value or Binding section?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have other Date Columns on the table?  Can you post the TSQL definition of the table?

Comment: I have a CreatedDate column and a ModifiedDate column. Both use the datetime2 data type (But I'm not sure how to get the ModifiedDate to work because it contains Null values). But how do I find the TSQL definition?

Answer (score 3):

If you only care about the year , you should use an `int` instead of a `datetime2`.

To have the column default to just the year, you can set the default value to `YEAR(GETDATE())`. This takes the current date (and time) and extracts the year as an `int`.

Comment: If I change the data type to int, how will SQL know that I want the year?

Comment: Is the data you're inputting to the table already a date? If it's not, you just insert the year as a number. If it is, then depending on how you're loading data, there are plenty of ways to get just the year from a date. If you really want to stick with a date column, you can use the [YEAR()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186313.aspx) function to get just the year part of the date when selecting data.

Comment: For example, my column HistoryYear, I want the year in which the data is inputted. So, I think the easiest way is to just use a datetime2 data type and just use the year. But when I used YEAR() in the default value or binding, with a data type of datetime2, I get an error saying "Error validating the default for column 'HistoryYear'.

Comment: That isn't how YEAR() works. If you just want the YEAR the data is input, for an int column you can specify a default of YEAR(GETDATE()). For a datetime2 column you would use just GETDATE(), which will be the exact time the record is inserted and not just the year. Trying to put just a year into a datetime field is more complicated and not recommended.

Comment: int -datatype and year(getdate()) was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much!